# How easy it is to develop drag and drop features using meteor js?

Tags: meteor

I need to design a website customization interface with drag & drop features list, and would like to build it using the meteor js framework and I'm new to this. Any suggestions or recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I recommend and suggest you to look things like that on google first http://differential.com/blog/sortable-lists-in-meteor-using-jquery-ui

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely do this sort of thing in Meteor.  Another good starting point:

https://github.com/nleush/meteor-todos-sortable-animation